# Поочередный запуск Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

При запуске основного `Activity` необходимо проверять заданы ли пользователем настройки. Если нет, то поочередно запускать два других Activity, где эти настройки задаются. Делал так, но они запускаются сразу оба, т.е. активным становиться второе, не дожидаясь результата отработки первого. Что я делаю не так?

```
if (preferences.getString("pref1", "Default value").equals("Default value") {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
if (preferences.getString("pref2", "Default value").equals("Default value") {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запускайте только `Activity1`, после выбора в нем настроек выполняйте `setResult` и `finish()`, а в методе `onActivityResult` основного `Activity` ловите сообщение от Activity1, и уже после запускайте Activity2. [Подробнее](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/69-urok-30-podrobnee-pro-onactivityresult-zachem-nuzhny-requestcode-i-resultcode.html).

Comment: Хорошо. А если первая настройка задана, а вторая нет? Или наоборот. Как быть в этом случае....

Comment: Если первая задана открывать сразу второе активити. Если только первое, то в методе onActivityResul второе не открывать

Answer (score 1):

В Android существует хранилище, там обычно хранят настройки приложения `SharedPreferences` поищите об этом в интернете.

Пример создания:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("view", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editorView = preferences.edit();
    editorView.putString("VIEW", "null");
    editorView.apply();
```

Пример взятие данных:

```
SharedPreferences preferencesView = getSharedPreferences("view",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String view = preferencesView.getString("VIEW"," ");
```

А далее вы просто проверяете ветвлением :)